# C - Deleting node from Binary Tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I want to know how to delete a node from a non-searching binary tree.

I.e. If I have this binary tree :

> ```
>    ....0....
>  ...1.....2...
> .......3.....4..
> ```

And I want do delete the node where the value is 2.

Comment: I don't understand the schema and Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a sorted tree (like a search tree), you would typically remove the node (`2` in your example) and replace it with either the right-most leaf of the left child subtree (`3`) or the left-most of the right subtree (`4`).  You may be able to do the same if it is not a binary search tree.  It depends, of course, on the semantics of your tree and what the structure represents (if anything).  If the structure carries no significance, then just remove the node you want to delete and replace it with any leaf node.

Comment: Should I link the right child of 0 to 3 and then link the right child of 3 to 4 and freeing the 2 ?

Comment: Don't forget about 2's left subtree! It may possibly contain more than just 3. Also be careful with the child pointers of 2 if you have a recursive routine to free allocations (you may need to set them to `NULL` before freeing node 2). Another option would be to just move the data (3) from the leaf where 3 is now to where the value you want to delete (2) is now, and then free the leaf node. Remember that the replacement must be from a leaf node.  (For example, if you wanted to delete 0, don't pick 2.)